# Inconsistent parsing of HTML comments containing backticks

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-preview

HTML comments and markdown special characters interact in a strange way. Let's fiddle with

```
<!-- foo `bar` qux -->
```

This apparent HTML comment ends at the first backtick:  qux -->

This apparent HTML comment isn't visible at all in the preview:  qux -->

If it's alone in its paragraph, it is parsed as a comment:

I'm not overly concerned as to how this edge case is parsed. I have preference for it to be treated as a comment, but no biggie. As far as I understand [CommonMark](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.20/#html-comment), all these snippets should be parsed as comments.

The fact that the preview differs from the final parsing is definitely a bug in any case.

Initially observed in the wild [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/211358/1).

Comment: _May_ be relevant http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297415/why-do-backticks-not-work-inside-html-lists

Comment: @RishavKundu That doesn't seem related. Unlike you, I'm not expecting the backticks to be interpreted as code delimiters.

Comment: @Giles I was referring to the fact that mixtures of Markdown and HTML generally don’t behave well. Also, Waylan’s answer may be significant.